# How to choose specified File to upload to Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I would like to upload my `SQLite` database File to Firebase Storage. My problem is that I can only find tutorials where the user has to choose the file manually, but I would like to send a fixed file, so you can't send other data to Firebase storage.
How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First get the reference to the firebase storage

```
// Create a storage reference from our app
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
```

Then to upload the file do the following:

```
Uri file = Uri.fromFile("sqlite_file");
StorageReference filesRef = storageRef.child("files");
uploadTask = filesRef.putFile(file);

// Register observers to listen for when the download is done or if it fails
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, etc.
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: it is red underscored

Comment: do `Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("sqlite_file"));`